# AWS Api Gateway mock integration response header mapping, how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was digging web and kept trying to find what I am missing in the following situation:
The basic problem I am trying to solve is: when http://example.com/login?target=http://google.com is called, the user is redirected to an OAuth login page with the state referring to the url in the target query param.

So:  `http://example.com/login?target=http://google.com`
would be redirected to
`http://authenticator.com/login?type=...&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...&state=http://google.com`

I could do this with Lambda, but I felt it is unnecessary and API Gateway could be used solely.

First I created the `/login` resource and a `GET` method, to which I added a mock integration.

[image: Integration Request]

I set 302 at Method Response:

[image: Method Response]

Finally I added Integration Response:

[image: Integration Response]

However when I test the method, the Location header is missing. If I put a static string to the Location header in Integration Response it works, but whatever I try at the header mapping it is not working.

Things I tried at Integration Request mapping:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {"target": "https://google.com"}
}
```

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "target": "https://google.com"
}
```

I seems that `integration.response.body.target` or `integration.response.header.target` is always empty.
According to the documentation, `headers` property can be part of the integration response, but I cannot get any value from the Mapping Template I set at Integration Request.

Any idea what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to map response body with header.I face the same issue it comes with empty space

Comment: @Jennings I spent a few more hours on this one at the end of December, but I have not checked it since then. Finally I ended up creating a Lambda function which does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a response override, eg: in your integration request

```
#set($urlProxy = $method.request.path.proxy)
{
    "statusCode": 301,
}
#set($context.responseOverride.header.location = "https://www.foo.bar.com/$urlProxy")
```

This will override your response header location

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to map from a header value but a header value is never being set, instead you're setting a property called "headers" in the body. In order to map a value from `integration.response.header.target` you're going to need to set that value in your mock in the HTTP Headers section of the Integration Request.

However you may find it simpler to set your request Mapping Template for the mock to

`{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "target": "https://google.com"
}`

and then you could then use a response mapping to set your `Location` header to `integration.response.body.target`

Comment: Integration Request has no "header" section for MOCK type. I tried this one, the Location header now presents, but has empty string as value.
From Lambda I use this form for api gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html
This is why I tried to use the "headers" property.

Comment: try using the template I've shown and access the value from integration.response.body.target instead of integration.response.header.target

Comment: That is what I exactly did. The Location header is an empty string when testing the method. I tried to use the whole body (`integration.response.body`) also, then I got an empty object (`{}`)